# Is it possible to convert a bytes object to a code object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I create a code object with the `compile` function, I can use `co_code` to convert the code object to a bytes object. However, I have not found a way to convert the bytes object back into a code object. Is it possible to do so? And if so, how?

the part of my code is:

```
    dire=dirent.get()
    file=filent.get()
    os.chdir(dire)
    lfile=list(file)
    if lfile[-1]=='y' and lfile[-2]=='p' and lfile[-3]=='.':
        del lfile[-1]
        del lfile[-1]
        del lfile[-1]
        pcfile=''
        for i in lfile:
            pcfile=pcfile+i
        cfile=pcfile+' compile.py'
        fite=open(file,'r',-1,'iso-8859-1')
        cobj=compile(fite.read(),file,'exec')
        ctext=cobj.co_code.__str__()
        with open(cfile,'w+') as cfe:
            cfe.write(ctext)
```

FYI: I expect the output to be executable with the `exec` function. Also I am using tkinter.

Comment: Probably not, unless you also know all the other `co_*` attributes of the code object

Comment: Show us the code you're currently running. Also, is writing to a `.pyc` file fair game?

Comment: @ForceBru And if I do?

Comment: @J_H I don't really mind what type of file it is written to

Comment: Wait, does that answer your question? I actually didn't mean to dupe-hammer your post... I wonder if it's possible _not_ to dupe-hammer questions right away, but just record the vote and post the "Possible duplicate..." comment

Comment: Or, if you're storing the values of the `co_*` attributes separately, you can construct the code object using [`types.CodeType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.CodeType).

Comment: @ForceBru I am quite new to code objects in python, so i don't quite know what to do with the `co_*` attributes when i have them.

Comment: You will likely find the code at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/35c08092a6eb70cdd723 to be useful. It is based on Ned Batchelder's excellent description: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html

Comment: @a_random_programmer, can you save the code object with `marshal` like in the possible duplicate? If so, then it's very simple and doesn't require you to understand the workings of code objects. Again, I'm sorry I dupe-hammered your question, I'm quite new to this power. If the dupe target doesn't answer your question, you should be able to vote to reopen and also let me know so I can vote to reopen too.

Comment: @ForceBru The question you marked mine as a duplicate of does answer my question. Although the answer did need some editing as the file must be opened in binary format. Thanks.